# ¿Cómo se simplifica este tipo de código?

Tags: c#, asp.net, revisión-de-código

¿Cómo se simplifica este tipo de código?
la idea es de cada consulta obtener una variable para según la variable direccionar al usuario según si es funcionario o es usuario normal, algo así como roles de usuarios, de forma manual.

```
//NIVEL DE ACCESO NECESARIO PARA ESTA APLICACION
            int app_Permissions;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT app_Permisos FROM Aplicativos WHERE app_Nombre='bloqMPM'", con);
                app_Permissions = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }

            int app_Area;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT app_Area FROM Aplicativos WHERE app_Nombre='bloqMPM'", con);
                app_Area = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }

            // token de usuario y aplicacion
            string app_Token;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT app_Token FROM Aplicativos WHERE app_Nombre='bloqMPM'", con);
                app_Token = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }

            string user_Token;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tokenUnico FROM Users WHERE Username=@Username", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["Username"].ToString());
                user_Token = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }
if (esFuncionarioPT == 1 && nivelAccesoUser >= app_Permissions && app_Area == areaUser || esFuncionarioPT == 1 && nivelAccesoUser >= app_Permissions && app_Token == user_Token)
            {...........
```

Comment: Me parece que tu pregunta puede cerrarse como _basada en opiniones_,tal vez si la formulas de otra manera... De todas maneras, te diré que cuantas menos consultas hagas a la BBDD mejor, con lo que lo mejor en tu caso sería obtener todos los campos en una única consulta por rendimiento de la aplicación y menos carga de la BBDD

Comment: Deberias decir que es lo que quieres mejorar del codigo. En su forma actual, las respuestas serian, es correcto si, porque anda. Es practico, dudoso, pq son muchas lineas de consulta a la misma tabla de la base de datos, pero por eso no deja de ser practico.

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia ya que haces tres preguntas en una: correcto, práctico y mejores formas y cada una, sin haber definido a qué te refieres con ellas, atrae respuestas basadas en opiniones. Enfoca tu pregunta en una cosa y describe que significa o has referencia a alguna guía  pero describe brevemente las premisas principales de la misma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hace muchas consultas innecesarias a la bd. Prueba con esto:

```
int app_Permissions, app_Area, app_Token;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    con.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT app_Permisos, app_Area, app_Token FROM Aplicativos WHERE app_Nombre='bloqMPM'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
    app_Permissions = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["app_Permisos"]);
    app_Area = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["app_Area"]);
    app_Token = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["app_Token"]);
}
```

En una consulta obtienes los 3 valores, en vez de hacer la misma 3 veces.

No es necesario cerrar la conexión ya que la directiva "using" se encarga de hacerlo.

Ahora dudo que lo que estás haciendo sea la mejor forma, porque desconozco el contexto, pero me da la impresión de que se puede hacer mucho mejor.

El resto del código lo puedes dejar igual.

Saludos.

Comment: Ya veo, @Gonzalo Bustamante, en cuanto al contexto, es aprendizaje, si sonspechaba que era algo como "perverso" realizar una consulta tras otra, pero no lograba interpretar el como preguntar correctamente para buscar en google, gracias compa! creo que lo que expones es justo lo que necesito analizar.